# Java Object Persistance

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to write code with fewer lines without losing processing efficiency. Consider this code:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    JSONObject main = = new JSONObject();
    main.put("RedApples", i);
    main.put("GreenApples", i);
    arr.add(main);
}
```

Now we know this is bad code because the JSONObject is declared inside the loop, so you'll have declared 10 different JSONObjects objects that stay in memory until the code is completed. We should want to declare the JSONObject outside of the array and simply set it inside the loop.

Now what about functions? If inside function there is an a JSONObject declared and that function is called 10 times will that hold all 10 in memory or does the memory get completely dumped when the function ends? I'm using this inside a servlet. I've tried searching for this but it is hard to look for what happens inside a function compared to the rest of the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed a few terms here. In your code example you aren't creating an object, you are declaring a variable of primitive type `int`. This variable is created on the stack. Each variable has a scope, which in this case is the loop's body. The variable's value is promised to be valid only in its scope, so when each iteration ends the variable is no longer in use (its memory can be reclaimed and use for other causes).

Same is true for methods - they declares a scope in which their declared variable are valid. When the function returns, the declared variables are no longer in use and their memory can reclaimed.

For more information check [Local Variables and Scope](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html)

Comment: The actual example I wanted to use was for JSONObjects and JSONArrays, that's what I'm actually working with in my code. int was just faster way to come up with an example. I've updated my question appropriately. Seems you answered my question at the end too, so thank you.

Comment: For objects there are different considerations, as they are created on the heap and reclaimed by the garbage collector once no one holds a reference to it. Creating an object inside a loop truely allocates memory on each iteration for the new object, but according to your example this seems as the right path, as you populates an array.

Comment: I was understanding it, told on this website I believe, is that the JSONObject should be outside of the loop, so that there is only one copy of it at any time. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

> so you'll have declared 10 different int objects that stay in memory until the code is completed

No, this is not how Java works. First of all, variables of a primitive type, such as `int`, are not objects. I don't know what exactly you mean by "until the code is completed", but the `int` variable that you declare inside the loop is not going to stay in memory beyond the body of the loop.

Declaring the variable outside the loop will make very little difference in efficiency or memory use.

Note that you can also write your loop like this, without the variable:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setApples(i * 5);
}
```

But even this is going to be almost exactly the same in practice as your original code.

It is normally not worth it to worry about micro-optimizations like these. The JVM is way smarter than most programmers realize - it contains many sophisticated optimizations to make your code run fast.

Comment: I meant to use JSONObject and JSONArray but went with int just for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you're trying to do here, is called "premature optimization". It's writing code with some idea of efficiency in mind, instead of writing readable, straightforward code. That typically results in code that is harder to read and maintain, and in most cases doesn't really improve program efficiency.

[If you want to optimize, analyze first, using a good profiler, and only then start to change your code in the places you found to be the hot spots.]

Answering the new code example with the JSONObject:

As result, you want a JSONArray containing 10 different JSONObjects that didn't exist beforehand. There's no way to avoid creating these 10 JSONObjects, and that's exactly what your code example does. If you just create one JSONObject outside the loop and set its fields to different values every loop iteration, you'll end up with a JSONArray containing 10 times the identical JSONObject, with field values from the latest iteration, as all the `setXXX()` calls will just modify the single object you created, and the last set wins. If you want 10 JSONObjects that differ in their field values, you need 10 instances, as a single instance can only hold a single set of values, no matter how often you add it to some list or array.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that all of the objects in the JSONArray will all be redapples, 10 and greenapples, 10?

Comment: Yes, if you move the `new JSONObject()` out of the loop.

Comment: I can personally attest that doesn't happen in Java EE. Once you add the object to the array you can change it's source value as much as you want. It's the fundamental basis of our application, pretty much everything we do uses that method.

Comment: I wasn't able to identify the exact JSONArray or JSONObject classes that you use, so sorry for my misguided advice. JSONArray seems to copy its elements or translate them to JSON strings immediately. Not the usual, expected behaviour for an `add()` method. Ok, I learned something new.